# Stress Test for gamma FX portfolios?

Tags: portfolio, gamma, stress

How can I create scenarios to stress gamma FX portfolios? If I shock the underlying for example +/-10%, then I gain in both scenarios. I get to capture some losses if I shock the implied volatility. Is this correct?